# Having trouble installing Net::Twitter from CPAN

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm trying to install Net::Twitter on Arch Linux ARM using cpanm, but I'm having trouble with dependencies. It looks like in some of them the dependencies depend on the module that needs the dependencies, but that seems impossible. How can I fix this? Here's my build.log:

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7001 on perl 5.018001 built for armv6l-linux-thread-multi
Work directory is /root/.cpanm/work/1388074479.18231
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have /usr/bin/wget
You have /usr/bin/tar: tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
Searching Net::Twitter on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Net::Twitter
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/MM/MMIMS/Net-Twitter-4.01000.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Net-Twitter-4.01000.tar.gz
Entering Net-Twitter-4.01000
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Checking if you have Module::Build 0.3601 ... Yes (0.4003)
Checking if you have Module::Build 0.36 ... Yes (0.4003)
Configuring Net-Twitter-4.01000
Running Build.PL
Checking prerequisites...
  requires:
    !  Data::Visitor::Callback is not installed
    !  HTML::Entities is not installed
    !  LWP::Protocol::https is not installed
    !  Moose is not installed
    !  Moose::Exporter is not installed
    !  Moose::Meta::Method is not installed
    !  Moose::Role is not installed
    !  MooseX::Role::Parameterized is not installed
    !  Net::OAuth is not installed
    !  namespace::autoclean is not installed
  build_requires:
    !  LWP::UserAgent is not installed
    !  Net::OAuth::Message is not installed

ERRORS/WARNINGS FOUND IN PREREQUISITES.  You may wish to install the versions
of the modules indicated above before proceeding with this installation

Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Net-Twitter' version '4.01000'
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have Net::Netrc 0 ... Yes (2.12)
Checking if you have DateTime::Format::Strptime 0 ... Yes (1.54)
Checking if you have base 0 ... Yes (2.18)
Checking if you have Net::HTTP >= 0, != 6.04, != 6.05 ... Yes (6.06)
Checking if you have HTTP::Request::Common 0 ... Yes (6.04)
Checking if you have overload 0 ... Yes (1.22)
Checking if you have Moose::Exporter 0 ... No
Checking if you have Digest::SHA 0 ... Yes (5.84_01)
Checking if you have Class::Load 0 ... Yes (0.20)
Checking if you have Test::More 0.88 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have File::Temp 0 ... Yes (0.2304)
Checking if you have HTTP::Response 0 ... Yes (6.04)
Checking if you have Net::OAuth 0 ... No
Checking if you have LWP::Protocol::https 0 ... No
Checking if you have namespace::autoclean 0 ... No
Checking if you have Data::Visitor::Callback 0 ... No
Checking if you have utf8 0 ... Yes (1.10)
Checking if you have Test::Fatal 0 ... Yes (0.013)
Checking if you have URI 0 ... Yes (1.60)
Checking if you have URI::Escape 0 ... Yes (3.31)
Checking if you have strict 0 ... Yes (1.07)
Checking if you have Net::OAuth::Message 0 ... No
Checking if you have Try::Tiny 0 ... Yes (0.18)
Checking if you have MooseX::Role::Parameterized 0 ... No
Checking if you have warnings 0 ... Yes (1.18)
Checking if you have Module::Build 0.3601 ... Yes (0.4003)
Checking if you have Time::HiRes 0 ... Yes (1.9725)
Checking if you have Carp::Clan 0 ... Yes (6.04)
Checking if you have HTML::Entities 0 ... No
Checking if you have Moose::Role 0 ... No
Checking if you have Test::Simple 0.98 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have JSON 0 ... Yes (2.90)
Checking if you have Moose::Meta::Method 0 ... No
Checking if you have DateTime 0 ... Yes (1.05)
Checking if you have Test::Warn 0 ... Yes (0.24)
Checking if you have List::Util 0 ... Yes (1.27)
Checking if you have File::Spec 0 ... Yes (3.40)
Checking if you have Devel::StackTrace 0 ... Yes (1.30)
Checking if you have Encode 0 ... Yes (2.49)
Checking if you have File::Find 0 ... Yes (1.23)
Checking if you have LWP::UserAgent 5.819 ... No
Checking if you have Moose 0 ... No
Checking if you have Scalar::Util 0 ... Yes (1.27)
Checking if you have Carp 0 ... Yes (1.29)
==> Found dependencies: Moose::Exporter, Net::OAuth, LWP::Protocol::https, namespace::autoclean, Data::Visitor::Callback, Net::OAuth::Message, MooseX::Role::Parameterized, HTML::Entities, Moose::Role, Moose::Meta::Method, LWP::UserAgent, Moose
Searching Moose::Exporter on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Moose::Exporter
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/Moose-2.1005.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Moose-2.1005.tar.gz
Entering Moose-2.1005
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have Dist::CheckConflicts 0.02 ... Yes (0.10)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.30 ... Yes (6.66)
Configuring Moose-2.1005
Running Makefile.PL
Warning: prerequisite Class::Load::XS 0.01 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Package::Stash::XS 0.24 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Sub::Name 0.05 not found.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Moose
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have Class::Load 0.09 ... Yes (0.20)
Checking if you have Test::Requires 0.05 ... Yes (0.07)
Checking if you have Package::Stash 0.32 ... Yes (0.36)
Checking if you have Params::Util 1.00 ... Yes (1.07)
Checking if you have Data::OptList 0.107 ... Yes (0.109)
Checking if you have Test::CheckDeps 0.006 ... No
Checking if you have MRO::Compat 0.05 ... Yes (0.12)
Checking if you have Class::Load::XS 0.01 ... No
Checking if you have CPAN::Meta::Check 0.007 ... No
Checking if you have Test::More 0.94 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have Eval::Closure 0.04 ... Yes (0.11)
Checking if you have Dist::CheckConflicts 0.02 ... Yes (0.10)
Checking if you have Sub::Exporter 0.980 ... Yes (0.987)
Checking if you have Test::Fatal 0.001 ... Yes (0.013)
Checking if you have Sub::Name 0.05 ... No
Checking if you have Try::Tiny 0.02 ... Yes (0.18)
Checking if you have Task::Weaken 0 ... Yes (1.04)
Checking if you have List::MoreUtils 0.28 ... Yes (0.33)
Checking if you have Package::Stash::XS 0.24 ... No
Checking if you have Scalar::Util 1.19 ... Yes (1.27)
Checking if you have Devel::GlobalDestruction 0 ... Yes (0.12)
Checking if you have Carp 1.22 ... Yes (1.29)
Checking if you have Package::DeprecationManager 0.11 ... Yes (0.13)
==> Found dependencies: Test::CheckDeps, Class::Load::XS, CPAN::Meta::Check, Sub::Name, Package::Stash::XS
Searching Test::CheckDeps on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Test::CheckDeps
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/L/LE/LEONT/Test-CheckDeps-0.010.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Test-CheckDeps-0.010.tar.gz
Entering Test-CheckDeps-0.010
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.30 ... Yes (6.66)
Configuring Test-CheckDeps-0.010
Running Makefile.PL
Warning: prerequisite CPAN::Meta::Check 0.007 not found.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Test::CheckDeps
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have IPC::Open3 0 ... Yes (1.13)
Checking if you have Test::Builder 0 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have IO::Handle 0 ... Yes (1.34)
Checking if you have List::Util 0 ... Yes (1.27)
Checking if you have File::Spec 0 ... Yes (3.40)
Checking if you have Exporter 5.57 ... Yes (5.68)
Checking if you have CPAN::Meta 2.120920 ... Yes (2.120921)
Checking if you have warnings 0 ... Yes (1.18)
Checking if you have CPAN::Meta::Check 0.007 ... No
Checking if you have Test::More 0.88 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have strict 0 ... Yes (1.07)
==> Found dependencies: CPAN::Meta::Check
Searching CPAN::Meta::Check on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on CPAN::Meta::Check
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/L/LE/LEONT/CPAN-Meta-Check-0.008.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking CPAN-Meta-Check-0.008.tar.gz
Entering CPAN-Meta-Check-0.008
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.30 ... Yes (6.66)
Configuring CPAN-Meta-Check-0.008
Running Makefile.PL
Warning: prerequisite CPAN::Meta::Prereqs 2.132830 not found. We have 2.120921.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for CPAN::Meta::Check
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have Test::More 0.88 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have Env 0 ... Yes (1.04)
Checking if you have strict 0 ... Yes (1.07)
Checking if you have Module::Metadata 0 ... Yes (1.000011)
Checking if you have IO::Handle 0 ... Yes (1.34)
Checking if you have warnings 0 ... Yes (1.18)
Checking if you have CPAN::Meta 2.120920 ... Yes (2.120921)
Checking if you have File::Spec 0 ... Yes (3.40)
Checking if you have Exporter 5.57 ... Yes (5.68)
Checking if you have Test::Deep 0 ... Yes (0.112)
Checking if you have CPAN::Meta::Prereqs 2.132830 ... No (2.120921 < 2.132830)
Checking if you have CPAN::Meta::Requirements 2.121 ... Yes (2.122)
Checking if you have IPC::Open3 0 ... Yes (1.13)
==> Found dependencies: CPAN::Meta::Prereqs
Searching CPAN::Meta::Prereqs on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on CPAN::Meta::Prereqs
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DA/DAGOLDEN/CPAN-Meta-2.133380.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking CPAN-Meta-2.133380.tar.gz
Entering CPAN-Meta-2.133380
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.17 ... Yes (6.66)
Configuring CPAN-Meta-2.133380
Running Makefile.PL
Warning: prerequisite List::Util 1.33 not found. We have 1.27.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for CPAN::Meta
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have Parse::CPAN::Meta 1.4403 ... Yes (1.4404)
Checking if you have strict 0 ... Yes (1.07)
Checking if you have Data::Dumper 0 ... Yes (2.145)
Checking if you have Carp 0 ... Yes (1.29)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.66)
Checking if you have Scalar::Util 0 ... Yes (1.27)
Checking if you have version 0.88 ... Yes (0.9902)
Checking if you have utf8 0 ... Yes (1.10)
Checking if you have List::Util 1.33 ... No (1.27 < 1.33)
Checking if you have File::Spec 0 ... Yes (3.40)
Checking if you have File::Spec::Functions 0 ... Yes (3.40)
Checking if you have IO::Dir 0 ... Yes (1.10)
Checking if you have Test::More 0.88 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have File::Temp 0.20 ... Yes (0.2304)
Checking if you have CPAN::Meta::YAML 0.008 ... Yes (0.008)
Checking if you have overload 0 ... Yes (1.22)
Checking if you have warnings 0 ... Yes (1.18)
Checking if you have CPAN::Meta::Requirements 2.121 ... Yes (2.122)
Checking if you have File::Basename 0 ... Yes (2.84)
Checking if you have JSON::PP 2.27200 ... Yes (2.27202)
==> Found dependencies: List::Util
Searching List::Util on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on List::Util
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/P/PE/PEVANS/Scalar-List-Utils-1.35.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Scalar-List-Utils-1.35.tar.gz
Entering Scalar-List-Utils-1.35
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.66)
Configuring Scalar-List-Utils-1.35
Running Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for List::Util
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have Test::More 0 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.66)
Building and testing Scalar-List-Utils-1.35
cp lib/Scalar/Util.pm blib/lib/Scalar/Util.pm
cp lib/List/Util.pm blib/lib/List/Util.pm
cp lib/List/Util/XS.pm blib/lib/List/Util/XS.pm
/usr/bin/perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtils/typemap  ListUtil.xs > ListUtil.xsc && mv ListUtil.xsc ListUtil.c
cc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -march=armv6 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4   -DVERSION=\"1.35\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.35\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE"  -DPERL_EXT ListUtil.c
/bin/sh: cc: command not found
Makefile:344: recipe for target 'ListUtil.o' failed
make: *** [ListUtil.o] Error 127
-> FAIL Installing List::Util failed. See /root/.cpanm/work/1388074479.18231/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
-> FAIL Installing the dependencies failed: Installed version (1.27) of List::Util is not in range '1.33'
-> FAIL Bailing out the installation for CPAN-Meta-2.133380.
-> FAIL Installing the dependencies failed: Installed version (2.120921) of CPAN::Meta::Prereqs is not in range '2.132830'
-> FAIL Bailing out the installation for CPAN-Meta-Check-0.008.
-> FAIL Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'CPAN::Meta::Check' is not installed
-> FAIL Bailing out the installation for Test-CheckDeps-0.010.
Searching Class::Load::XS on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Class::Load::XS
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DR/DROLSKY/Class-Load-XS-0.06.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Class-Load-XS-0.06.tar.gz
Entering Class-Load-XS-0.06
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have Module::Build 0.3601 ... Yes (0.4003)
Checking if you have Module::Build 0.36 ... Yes (0.4003)
Configuring Class-Load-XS-0.06
Running Build.PL
Warning: ExtUtils::CBuilder not installed or no compiler detected
Proceeding with configuration, but compilation may fail during Build

Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Class-Load-XS' version '0.06'
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have XSLoader 0 ... Yes (0.16)
Checking if you have strict 0 ... Yes (1.07)
Checking if you have Test::More 0.88 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have constant 0 ... Yes (1.27)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::CBuilder 0 ... Yes (0.280210)
Checking if you have version 0 ... Yes (0.9902)
Checking if you have warnings 0 ... Yes (1.18)
Checking if you have Test::Fatal 0 ... Yes (0.013)
Checking if you have Module::Build 0.3601 ... Yes (0.4003)
Checking if you have Test::Requires 0 ... Yes (0.07)
Checking if you have Class::Load 0.20 ... Yes (0.20)
Checking if you have Module::Implementation 0.04 ... Yes (0.07)
Building and testing Class-Load-XS-0.06
Building Class-Load-XS
Error: no compiler detected to compile 'lib/Class/Load/XS.c'.  Aborting
-> FAIL Installing Class::Load::XS failed. See /root/.cpanm/work/1388074479.18231/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
Already tried CPAN::Meta::Check. Skipping.
Searching Sub::Name on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Sub::Name
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/F/FL/FLORA/Sub-Name-0.05.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Sub-Name-0.05.tar.gz
Entering Sub-Name-0.05
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.66)
Configuring Sub-Name-0.05
Running Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Sub::Name
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.66)
Building and testing Sub-Name-0.05
cp lib/Sub/Name.pm blib/lib/Sub/Name.pm
/usr/bin/perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtils/typemap  Name.xs > Name.xsc && mv Name.xsc Name.c
cc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -march=armv6 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4   -DVERSION=\"0.05\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.05\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE"   Name.c
/bin/sh: cc: command not found
Makefile:326: recipe for target 'Name.o' failed
make: *** [Name.o] Error 127
-> FAIL Installing Sub::Name failed. See /root/.cpanm/work/1388074479.18231/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
Searching Package::Stash::XS on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Package::Stash::XS
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DO/DOY/Package-Stash-XS-0.28.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Package-Stash-XS-0.28.tar.gz
Entering Package-Stash-XS-0.28
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.30 ... Yes (6.66)
Configuring Package-Stash-XS-0.28
Running Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Package::Stash::XS
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have Test::Requires 0 ... Yes (0.07)
Checking if you have base 0 ... Yes (2.18)
Checking if you have Test::Fatal 0 ... Yes (0.013)
Checking if you have warnings 0 ... Yes (1.18)
Checking if you have File::Find 0 ... Yes (1.23)
Checking if you have B 0 ... Yes (1.42_01)
Checking if you have Test::More 0.88 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have File::Temp 0 ... Yes (0.2304)
Checking if you have XSLoader 0 ... Yes (0.16)
Checking if you have strict 0 ... Yes (1.07)
Checking if you have constant 0 ... Yes (1.27)
Checking if you have Symbol 0 ... Yes (1.07)
Checking if you have Scalar::Util 0 ... Yes (1.27)
Building and testing Package-Stash-XS-0.28
cp lib/Package/Stash/XS.pm blib/lib/Package/Stash/XS.pm
/usr/bin/perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap  XS.xs > XS.xsc && mv XS.xsc XS.c
cc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -march=armv6 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4   -DVERSION=\"0.28\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.28\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE"   XS.c
/bin/sh: cc: command not found
Makefile:330: recipe for target 'XS.o' failed
make: *** [XS.o] Error 127
-> FAIL Installing Package::Stash::XS failed. See /root/.cpanm/work/1388074479.18231/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
-> FAIL Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Class::Load::XS' is not installed, Module 'Test::CheckDeps' is not installed, Module 'CPAN::Meta::Check' is not installed, Module 'Sub::Name' is not installed, Module 'Package::Stash::XS' is not installed
-> FAIL Bailing out the installation for Moose-2.1005.
Searching Net::OAuth on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Net::OAuth
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/K/KG/KGRENNAN/Net-OAuth-0.28.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Net-OAuth-0.28.tar.gz
Entering Net-OAuth-0.28
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Checking if you have Module::Build 0.36 ... Yes (0.4003)
Checking if you have Module::Build 0.36 ... Yes (0.4003)
Configuring Net-OAuth-0.28
Running Build.PL
Checking prerequisites...
  requires:
    !  Digest::SHA1 is not installed
    !  LWP::UserAgent is not installed

ERRORS/WARNINGS FOUND IN PREREQUISITES.  You may wish to install the versions
of the modules indicated above before proceeding with this installation

Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Net-OAuth' version '0.28'
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have LWP::UserAgent 1 ... No
Checking if you have Test::More 0.66 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have Digest::SHA1 2.12 ... No
Checking if you have Test::Warn 0.21 ... Yes (0.24)
Checking if you have Encode 2.35 ... Yes (2.49)
Checking if you have URI::Escape 3.28 ... Yes (3.31)
Checking if you have Class::Data::Inheritable 0.06 ... Yes (0.08)
Checking if you have Class::Accessor 0.31 ... Yes (0.34)
Checking if you have Digest::SHA 5.47 ... Yes (5.84_01)
Checking if you have Digest::HMAC_SHA1 1.01 ... Yes (1.03)
==> Found dependencies: LWP::UserAgent, Digest::SHA1
Searching LWP::UserAgent on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on LWP::UserAgent
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/libwww-perl-6.05.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking libwww-perl-6.05.tar.gz
Entering libwww-perl-6.05
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.66)
Configuring libwww-perl-6.05
Running Makefile.PL
Warning: prerequisite HTML::Entities 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite HTML::HeadParser 0 not found.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for LWP
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have File::Listing 6 ... Yes (6.04)
Checking if you have HTTP::Daemon 6 ... Yes (6.01)
Checking if you have HTML::HeadParser 0 ... No
Checking if you have MIME::Base64 2.1 ... Yes (3.13)
Checking if you have HTTP::Response 6 ... Yes (6.04)
Checking if you have IO::Select 0 ... Yes (1.21)
Checking if you have HTML::Entities 0 ... No
Checking if you have HTTP::Request::Common 6 ... Yes (6.04)
Checking if you have Net::HTTP 6.04 ... Yes (6.06)
Checking if you have HTTP::Negotiate 6 ... Yes (6.01)
Checking if you have HTTP::Status 6 ... Yes (6.03)
Checking if you have HTTP::Date 6 ... Yes (6.02)
Checking if you have Digest::MD5 0 ... Yes (2.52)
Checking if you have LWP::MediaTypes 6 ... Yes (6.02)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.66)
Checking if you have IO::Socket 0 ... Yes (1.36)
Checking if you have Encode::Locale 0 ... Yes (1.03)
Checking if you have WWW::RobotRules 6 ... Yes (6.02)
Checking if you have HTTP::Cookies 6 ... Yes (6.01)
Checking if you have URI::Escape 0 ... Yes (3.31)
Checking if you have Net::FTP 2.58 ... Yes (2.77)
Checking if you have HTTP::Request 6 ... Yes (6.00)
Checking if you have URI 1.10 ... Yes (1.60)
Checking if you have Encode 2.12 ... Yes (2.49)
==> Found dependencies: HTML::HeadParser, HTML::Entities
Searching HTML::HeadParser on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on HTML::HeadParser
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/HTML-Parser-3.71.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking HTML-Parser-3.71.tar.gz
Entering HTML-Parser-3.71
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.66)
Configuring HTML-Parser-3.71
Running Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for HTML::Parser
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have XSLoader 0 ... Yes (0.16)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.66)
Checking if you have HTML::Tagset 3 ... Yes (3.20)
Building and testing HTML-Parser-3.71
cp lib/HTML/HeadParser.pm blib/lib/HTML/HeadParser.pm
cp Parser.pm blib/lib/HTML/Parser.pm
cp lib/HTML/LinkExtor.pm blib/lib/HTML/LinkExtor.pm
cp lib/HTML/TokeParser.pm blib/lib/HTML/TokeParser.pm
cp lib/HTML/PullParser.pm blib/lib/HTML/PullParser.pm
cp lib/HTML/Entities.pm blib/lib/HTML/Entities.pm
cp lib/HTML/Filter.pm blib/lib/HTML/Filter.pm
/usr/bin/perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap  Parser.xs > Parser.xsc && mv Parser.xsc Parser.c
```

etc, continued here: http://pastebin.com/YgbQjsJz

Answer (score 2):

Most of these errors seem to result from `make` not being able to find `cc` (the C compiler). `cc` would normally be a symlink pointing to `gcc`. You could try this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/cc
```

Comment: He might now have `gcc` installed. He should start by checking if he has `gcc` (by typing `gcc` at the prompt). If not, installing it will probably create `cc` in the process.

Comment: I didn't have gcc installed, installing it fixed most of it. However, I'm missing LWP::Protocol::https. It requires IO::Socket::SSL. However, I can't compile IO::Socket::SSL without Net::SSLeay, and I can't compile Net::SSLeay without IO::Socket::SSL. When I look at the build.log, it has a strange error `{standard input}: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
cc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)` and it asks me to submit a bug report. Can I fix this, or do I have to wait for it to be fixed? Full log: http://pastebin.com/9X4vttsu